# Burninate the [calc] tag?

Tags: feature-request, burninate-request

The [calc](/questions/tagged/calc) tag is used to refer to a program that does calculations, a CSS function called `calc`, OpenOffice Calc, `calc.exe` (I'm not totally sure what that is), and a few other things that have nothing to do with calculations. There are already tags for all of those except calc.exe, which are much more specific and should be used instead. There is so much confusion nobody has written a tag wiki summary for the thing. There is no consistent meaning. Can it be burninated please?

Comment: Synonymize with [tag:calculator] instead (remove where not appropriate)?

Comment: @Dukeling: as far as I can tell, that would involve removing it from just *nearly* all of the questions instead of all of them. I don't think it's generally used as a synonym at all.

Comment: @Wooble Assuming of course [tag:calculator] can also refer to calculator programs (which plenty of the questions do), I see plenty of [tag:calc] questions about that, at least on the tags I'm not ignoring.

Comment: `calc` is apparently a `css` function.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [tag:calc] is also used to refer to a program that does calculations, OpenOffice Calc, `calc.exe` (I'm not totally sure what that is), and a few other things that have nothing to do with calculations. There are already tags for all of those but `calc.exe` which are much more specific and should be used instead.

Comment: `calc.exe` is Windows' built-in [calculator](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TN3y3.png)

Comment: @hjpotter92 thank you, you are right